# Joomla search for Magento products

Tags: forms, magento, search, joomla

I currently have Joomla and Magento. I want using Joomla search module, get redirected into Magento search results, so I need to retrieve variable from Joomla search field and send it to Magento.

I don't know where to find the name of passing variable. What I have learned so far:
In `modules/mod_search/tmpl/default.php` 
I've changed search form action into magento search page:
`<form action="/magento/catalogsearch/result/?q=....." method="post">` of course, search variable should be instead of `.....`, if I add something manually, it works, but I do not know how to transfer search variable.

I want this as simple as possible, but it seems the solution is more complex or I am searching in a wrong place.

Thank you!

---

Comment: The Joomla module is simply getting the data from the database and displaying it. So all you would need to do is add a script to your Magento site (not sure how this is done as I have never used Magento) to connect to the Joomla database and get some data from a table.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question for a better explanation. I do not need to access Joomla database, just to send variable (that I submited in Joomla search form) to Magento search result page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**: Since I am not good with playing in other TVS playground, I retrieved keyword from array (Joomla sends that way) in `com_search/views/search/view.html.php` and made redirect with `header();` to a Magento search result page with that keyword. Hopefully I will manage to make it more professional next time.